# Is there bias in matrix multiplications for self attention

Tags: transformer, bert, attention-mechanism

When the query matrix Q is computed as $XW_Q$,  ($W_Q$ is the weight matrix for the queries), is it implemented as a linear layer without bias? I see some blogs saying there is are bias terms as well.

To paraphrase the question in a different way, are there bias terms when Q , K and V are computed using a linear layer in pytorch? If yes, why does it make sense since adding bias makes the transformation a non linear one

Comment: Adding a bias term does not make the transformation non-linear, it's the activation function that does this. The bias term translates the function left or right.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you got an answer, but I recently had a similar question when looking at a transformer implemented in code.The QKV projection step does not seem to involve a bias, as shown in this code snippet from (https://github.com/lucidrains/x-transformers/tree/main)

```
to_qkv = nn.Linear(dim, inner_dim * 3, bias = False)
```